# (Android MediaPlayer) How am I supposed to call setAudioStreamType() if MediaPlayer.create() implicitly calls prepare()?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am writing an Android alarm application that uses a Service in order to play the alarm tone. Currently, I am able to get the audio to play, but it plays in a form that can be muted by turning down the device's volume. Thus, I am trying to add a call to `setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);` to prevent this.

I have the following for my `onStartCommand()` function for the service:

```
MediaPlayer mMP;    
@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        try
        {
            mMP = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.alarm);
            mMP.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
            mMP.setLooping(true);
            //mMP.prepare(); commented out since prepare() is called in create
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (mMP != null) mMP.start();

        return START_STICKY;
    }
```

My problem is that with the call to setAudioStreamType(), the MediaPlayer never plays the audio. If I comment that line out, the audio plays.

With the line in, I get the following runtime error(s):

> 04-10 19:32:03.115: E/MediaPlayer(3411): setAudioStream called in state 8
>
> 04-10 19:32:03.115: E/MediaPlayer(3411): error (-38, 0)
>
> 04-10 19:32:03.115: E/MediaPlayer(3411): start called in state 0
>
> 04-10 19:32:03.115: E/MediaPlayer(3411): error (-38, 0)
>
> 04-10 19:32:03.115: E/MediaPlayer(3411): Error (-38,0)
>
> 04-10 19:32:03.115: E/MediaPlayer(3411): Error (-38,0)

Some research (I can't find the link now) told me that `setAudioStreamType()` can't be called after `prepare()` has been called, and that `create()` implicitly calls `prepare()`.

In any regard, how am I supposed to `setAudioStreamType()` without such an error?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can either call `mp.reset()` and then set the stream type, data source, and then prepare.  Alternately just use the default constructor and handle the initialization yourself.

EDIT:

```
Resources res = getResources();
AssetFileDescriptor afd = res.openRawResourceFd(R.raw.alarm);

mp.reset();
mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
mp.setLooping(true);
mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
```

Comment: It sounds like you are suggesting something along these lines (starting after the call to `create()`): `reset();` `setAudioStreamType();` `setLooping();` `prepare();`
Am I correct? If so, I get the following error on the call to prepare: `04-10 20:06:25.515: E/MediaPlayer(845): start called in state 1`
`04-10 20:06:25.515: E/MediaPlayer(845): error (-38, 0)
`

Comment: Seems like you're getting the error on the call to `start()` actually, not `prepare()`. Can you add your updated code to the question?

Comment: You are right, that particular error was arisen after the call to start, there is also an error on the call to prepare that I missed in the log when I was posting my comment. `04-10 21:42:11.896: E/MediaPlayer(593): prepareAsync called in state 1`.

Comment: Also, the only difference between what I'm trying now and what is posted above is that the `prepare()` call is uncommented, and `reset()` is called right after `create()`.

Comment: Are you ever calling `setDataSource()`? Otherwise it has no idea where your file is.

Comment: I'm not, but its learning of the data source in `create()`, when I pass it `R.raw.alarm`. Do I now need to call `setDataSource()` because of the call to `reset()`? If so, how would I do it referencing the file given that its in the `res/raw` directory of my project?

Comment: Yeah, once you reset it, it's completely uninitialized, which is why I'm fairly certain you can just use the default constructor (unless there's some base functionality in the `create()` method that has to be initialized other than the functions shown above) and save the call to `create()` entirely. Try the above example and let me know if that works for you.

Comment: That did it. Thanks a lot. I hadn't realized that `reset()` completely resets the MediaPlayer. Thanks a million for providing the code for the file descriptor, I haven't had to use that in Android yet, and it probably would have taken some time to figure out.

Comment: You're welcome! It's one of those not really obvious things to use, but once you've used it once or twice it sticks in your head. :)

Comment: This is an old question and an old answer, but it's still getting some views, so just to let you know, you don't have to call `create()` if does the wrong thing, or too much for your case. It's supposed to be a "convenience method" that does a lot for you for free in the common case. But since you're calling `reset()` to undo it anyway, you should really just create the media player yourself by `new MediaPlayer()` and then configure it freely and call `prepare()` whenever you're ready.

Comment: It's still not clear to me what the equivalent of `create(Context, int resid)` is, given that *no* `setDataSource` function takes an equivalent parameter!

Answer (score 3):

Accepted answer was throwing an *IllegalStateException*. This is working

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

try {
  mediaPlayer.setDataSource(
          this,
          getCustomToneUri()
  );

  mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION);

  mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
      mp.start();
    }
  });

  mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```