# Play file mp3 use volume of ringtone programmatically

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, media

I try to run file mp3 with volume of ringtone (not of media, alarm or notification), but it not working. My code:

```
AudioManager mAudioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    mAudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
    mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(
            AudioManager.STREAM_RING,
            mAudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING),
            AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
    mAudioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);

    MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();

    try {
        mp.setDataSource(this, Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.nhaccho));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
    mp.setLooping(true);
    try {
        mp.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mp.start();
```

please help. thanks!

Comment: " mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);" is the right way to do it . You can look into [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10098032/4168607) for calling it.

Comment: thank @NouMan Ch, i replace AudioManager.MODE_RINGTONE, it's ok but setSpeakerphoneOn(true|false) not working. Can you fix it?